# Creating a scrolling page without a plug-in. No scroll effect

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a one page scrolling site without using a plugin. Following this tutorial https://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2
The links work but there is no scrolling effect, it just jumps to the section.

JS

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
if( target.length ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
});
```

HTML (updated to remove errors)

```
<div id="container">

<div class="banner">
<a class="button" href="#welcome"><h2 style="text-align: center;"></h2></a>
</div>

<div id="page1">
<a id="welcome"></a>
<h1></h1>

<div id="welcome_squares">

<div class="quarter-column">
    <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
</div>

<div class="quarter-column">
    <a href="#info">
        <div class="welcome_square">
            <img src="/pageassets/" alt="" />
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="quarter-column">
    <a href="#events">
        <div class="welcome_square">
            <img src="/pageassets/" alt="" />
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="quarter-column">
    <a href="#contact">
        <div class="welcome_square">
            <img src="/pageassets/" alt="" />
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="full-column" id="tiles">
<a id="info"></a>
//CONTENT
</div>

<div class="full-column" id="tiles">
<a id="events"></a>
//CONTENT
</div>

<div id="contact">
<a id="contact"></a>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Does the console print any sort of errors?

Comment: No, no errors in the console

Comment: Well you have both divs with same ID... which is bad. If you `console.log(target);` and `console.log(target.length);` what happens?

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of mistakes in the code you presented,so it's hard to tell what your original problem was.  Here's a working fiddle based on your example.

https://jsfiddle.net/1dqhqpet/1/

I used the `id` attribute on anchors you place in the document to identify the location of a field you want to "go to".  I also didn't put the content inside the anchor tags, because that is not how you do that normally.  The anchor tag is a marker.  But I don't see why that would be too much of a problem (although with the `href` on the anchor tag that would turn the whole text into a link).  As you can see, since I didn't have access to your images I put some filler content in so you can see it scroll, but again, that shouldn't really affect anything.

**It's likely your problem is not in the code you presented.**

---

Some further notes on your code:

1. I know it was copy pasted, but you have an extra `</div>` after each `//Content` comment which makes it not working HTML
2. Your anchors that are used to identify the location of portions of the document don't need `href` attributes either.  All they need is `id`.  So

`<a id="welcome" href="#"></a>`

in your example becomes

`<a id="welcome"></a>`

3. Note that the content shouldn't go *in* the anchor tag either.  It should go under it.  The anchor is just like a bookmark to identify a portion of the page.
4. Based on how this works, the JQuery is only there to provide "smooth" scrolling.  It works just fine without it.

Comment: The browser can scroll to divs by id too

Comment: *name* attribute is [obsolete in HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-name).

Comment: Yeah, even after fixing these errors the smooth scrolling effects does not work. It just jumps to the sections

Comment: @user3005003 that's why I said your problem is probably somewhere else.  Because my fiddle does have the scrolling effect.

Answer (score -1):

Hey here's the Fiddle which is working.

https://jsfiddle.net/fj1dfcsr/2/

Errors I've encountered.

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="banner">
    <a class="button" href="#welcome"><h2 style="text-align: center;"></h2></a>
    </div>

    <div id="page1">
    <a id="welcome" href="#"></a>
    <h1></h1>

    <div id="welcome_squares">

    <div class="quarter-column">
        <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
    </div>

    <div class="quarter-column">
        <a href="#info">
            <div class="welcome_square">
                <img src="/pageassets/" alt="" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="quarter-column">
        <a href="#events">
            <div class="welcome_square">
                <img src="/pageassets/" alt="" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="quarter-column">
        <a href="#contact">
            <div class="welcome_square">
                <img src="/pageassets/" alt="" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="full-column" id="tiles">
    <a id="info" href="#">INfo</a> //Here, you have used </div> instead of </a>
    </div>

    <div class="full-column" id="tiles">
    <a id="events" href="#"></a> //Here also, you have used </div> instead of </a>
    </div>

    <div id="contact">
    <a href="#" id="contact"></a>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Few things you should keep in mind that you are calling a particular div whose id you know.

For example

`<div id="home"></div>`

then you'll have to use `<a href="#home">Home</a>`

not `<a id="#home"> Home </a>` //Wrong way

Comment: your ids are wrong. your "errors I've encountered" message before the code makes no sense, and the code in question points to anchor tags, not divs, so talking about the divs makes no sense either.  Oh yeah, and your jsfiddle doesn't work either.

Comment: @deltree ya i've got it. but fiddle is working fine. I've tried again.

Comment: just to verify, I made the display part of the fiddle very small so that it actually had a scrollbar and then clicked on the info link.  It scrolled to the top of the page.  So, no:  The fiddle isn't working.

Comment: Ya true, its because I've added the "id="container" on each anchor tag to demonstrate scroll is working.

Comment: @deltree click the "hi" and it will scroll to "welcome" veeeery slowly, as it should.